# Como agregar valores a un detalle sin duplicarlos

Tags: java, sql-server

Buen día a todos
espero me puedan ayudar con esta duda tengo una tabla en java donde cargo registros desde mi tabla detalle en sql server, como muestra en la imagen.

[image: Tabla de detalle]

Los campos que tiene la tabla en la base de datos son los mismos que los de la imagen, estos datos pertenecen a un pedido que ya fue realizado,pero sigue vigente lo que quiero hacer es que al momento de agregar otro detalle a la tabla y realizar el `insert` me inserte solo los nuevos registros y los que ya estaban los ignore pero hasta ahora no he podido hacerlo espero me puedan ayudar gracias por su tiempo.

Comment: Hola, por favor lee [ask] y edita la pregunta con las recomendaciones que encontrarás allí. Por ejemplo, las preguntas no deberían basarse principalmente en una imagen porque no todo el mundo puede ver el contenido de la imagen y las hacen menos accesibles y más difíciles de leer.

Answer (score 0):

Con este primer algoritmo puedes construir la sentencia que te permitiría modificar en base de datos el valor de interés. Uno a la vez.

```
public void actualizarBD(int id, String valor, int columna){
    String sentencia = "UPDATE zapateria.productos SET ";


    switch(columna){ // se concatena la sentencia de modificar la tabla con la columna de interes
        case 0:
            sentencia += "SUELA = '"+valor+"' ";
            break;
        case 1: 
            sentencia += "COLOR = '"+valor+"' ";
            break;
            // Agregar el resto de las columnas. Ignoradas por simplicidad
        default:
            break;
    }

    // Se coloca la ultima parte de la sentencia
    sentencia += "WHERE id = "+id+";";

    System.out.println("sentencia : "+sentencia);
}
```

Posteriormente se agrega un listener a la tabla especificamente al DefaultTableModel que es quien contiene la data de la misma, para saber si hubo algun cambio y donde cambio y que nuevo valor se agrego.

```
// Se agrega un evento que escuche cada vez que cambie un campo en la tabla grafica
    tabla.getModel().addTableModelListener(new TableModelListener() {
        @Override
        public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) { // se obtiene la fila y columna del elemento que cambio
            int fila = e.getFirstRow();
            int columna = e.getColumn();
            String valor = (String) tabla.getModel().getValueAt(fila, columna); // se obtiene el valor que cambio

            System.out.println("fila: "+fila);
            System.out.println("columna: "+columna);
            System.out.println("valor: "+valor);

            new Conexion().actualizarBD(1, valor, columna); // se actualiza la base de datos por cada elemento que cambie
            // Se necesitaria una ventana de confirmacion


        }
    });
```

Toda mejora que puedas agregar es valido siempre que obtengas lo que necesites y solventes tu duda.